# Understanding accuracy specification for an electronic load box

Tags: accuracy, electronic-load

I am using a BK Precision 8600 electronic load box. I am using it in constant resistance mode (CR mode). I have two resistances I am using, 15Ω and 5Ω, and I am interested in determining the max/min for each value. I have attached a relevant portion of the datasheet. Can someone please help me interpret it and apply it to my values? Also, what is meant by "I>10% of range)

[image]

Full Datasheet link:
https://bkpmedia.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads/datasheets/en-us/8600_Series_datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manufacturer:

"In Constant Resistance mode the unit will sink a current linearly proportional to the input voltage in accordance with the programmed resistance. The difference here is the resistance is simulated; it is not an actual resistor being placed in the circuit. As such, CR mode has to continually monitor the voltage applied and adjust the current accordingly in order to maintain the programmed resistance.

Resistance may be programmed in overlapping ranges. Some of the larger resistance ranges could be very inaccurate. You should compare the programming accuracy for both CC and CR mode.

Electronic Loads are not a conventional "resistor". The loads consist of IC's, capacitors, resistors, FETs, etc. The constant resistance (CR) mode in the load actually operates using either the constant current (CC) or constant voltage (CV) circuits inside the load. These circuits are used to simulate resistance in the specified ranges. When the CV or CC circuits are used, the load can be viewed as many resistors (Series or Parallel), with a specific value to produce the desired resistance. Resolution that can be programmed is: 80 mS (= 12.5 ohms ) or 0.8 mS (= 1.250 kohms)."[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I >10% of range, means these values are valid as long as the current is 10% or more than the maximum range. So if you're using the 8600/B in the low setting, you must be sinking at least 300mA for the accuracy to be valid.

For the accuracy, this probably merits an email to the manufacturer. 
0.01% + 0.08 S, suggests to me an acuracy of 0.01% of the set value, plus 0.08 siemens. This format is not unusual, but 0.08 siemens is 12.5 Ω, and would seem odd to me to have an accuracy of 12.5 Ω for a 0.05Ω set point.